# Inserting row into SQL table with some predefined values, and some from another table as well as join string.

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

Hi I am trying to run this query below:

```
INSERT INTO Database2.Table2 ('1', getdate(), getdate(), '',ID,'','0','0','0','',ID,'','',getdate(),getdate(),'','0','"stackoverflow.com/"'+'ID','0','product','','0') 
SELECT ID
FROM Database1.Table1;
```

I am inserting a new row with constant data mixed with data from another table, this case Database1.Table1 "ID". I constantly keep getting a select statement error when I try to run this code. Is there something I am overseeing or is this statement all wrong? Thank You

Comment: Do you really need both single and double quotes around `stackoverflow.com/`? And why are you quoting `ID` after that? That's the same as just writing `'"stackoverflow.com/"ID'`. Is that ID supposed to be unquoted, so it gets it from `Table1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the constants into the `SELECT` list.

```
INSERT INTO Database2.Table2 
SELECT '1', getdate(), getdate(), '',ID,'','0','0','0','',ID,'','',getdate(),getdate(),
       '','0',CONCAT('"stackoverflow.com/"','ID'),'0','product','','0', ID
FROM Database1.Table1;
```

BTW, I strongly recommend you get out of the habit of using `INSERT` without listing the column names before the values. Depending on the specific order of columns in the table definition is very error-prone.

Also, MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation by default, it uses the `CONCAT()` function.

Comment: But MySQL _can_ use the ANSI concatenation operator `||`, if a certain flag is set +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added "by default", since that flag is probably rarely set.